# Combine multiple SQL Queries for speed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with roughly 10 million rows and a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT output FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price
```

In addition to the above, I want to get:

- The mean average of the results returned
- The standard deviation of the results returned
- The total number of results returned
- The percentage of results that are positive

The problem with my existing code (shown below) is that I am querying the table multiple times. This seems very inefficient.

Is it possible to query the database once and then extract information like average, standard deviation, *etc*. from the results? And if so, what would be the most efficient approach?

```
SELECT STDDEV_POP(output) FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price
SELECT AVG(output) FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price
SELECT COUNT(output) FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price AND output > 0
SELECT COUNT(output) FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price AND output < 0
```

***Edit Is it also possible to get the actual "output" values in addition to the mean, standard deviation, and percent positive? In other words, could the following query also be incorporated?

```
SELECT output FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price
```

Comment: ***Edit Is it also possible to get the actual "output" values in addition to the mean, standard deviation, and percentage positive?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  In this case, you just want some conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT STDDEV_POP(output) as stddev_pop,
       AVG(output) as avg,
       SUM(output > 0) as output_gt_0,
       SUM(output < 0) as output_lt_0
FROM `table`
WHERE MA > Price;
```

Comment: most efficient solution

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the great reply. Is it also possible to get the actual "output" values in addition to the mean, standard deviation, and percentage positive?

Comment: @NedHulton  . . . I don't understand.  This returns one row, but  you seem to be asking for many rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one query like this

```
SELECT STDDEV_POP(output)
AVG(output),
count(case when output>0 then 1 else 0 end) as count1,
count(case when output<0 then 1 else 0 end) as count2,
FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price
```

Comment: you don't need the case statements when the condition evals to the value you want.

Comment: Hi Cableload, thanks for the great reply. Is it also possible to get the actual "output" values in addition to the mean, standard deviation, and percentage positive?

Answer (score 1):

You could try grabbing them all with one query

```
   SELECT STDDEV_POP(output),AVG(output),
   SUM(output>0),
   SUM(output<0) FROM `table` WHERE MA > Price
```

Comment: Hi Tin Tan, thanks for the great reply. Is it also possible to get the actual "output" values in addition to the mean, standard deviation, and percentage positive?

Comment: I think you'll have to run different queries. because these functions are aggregate functions, if you want individual output values you'll have to run another query. That's what you want isn't it individual output values?